# Regular expression in java to replace my placeholders with hashmap data

Tags: java, regex

I have a template with placeholders

```
Dear [[user.firstname]] [[user.lastname]] 

Message [[other.msg]]
```

And I a have collection of data in Map

```
Map data = new HashMap();  
data.put("user.firstname","John");
data.put("user.lastname","Kannan");    
data.put("other.msg","Message goes here...");
```

I would like to create a Java regular expression to replace map data value with associated placeholder (within `[[]]`) on my template.

Comment: Note that this problem is easier to solve due to the fact that the keys in your HashMap are literal, plain texts. If they are regular expressions, the problem becomes much harder.

Answer (score 14):

You can't do that using regex alone in Java, you need to wrap it in some logic.

Here's a method that does this for you:

```
public static String replaceValues(final String template,
    final Map<String, String> values){

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    final Pattern pattern =
        Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]", Pattern.DOTALL);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(template);
    while(matcher.find()){
        final String key = matcher.group(1);
        final String replacement = values.get(key);
        if(replacement == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
               "Template contains unmapped key: "
                + key);
        }
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need a regex for this? Why not simply do :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> replacement : data.entrySet()) {
    s = s.replace("[[" + replacement.getKey() + "]]", replacement.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Imagine your map is 1 million keys and you have to convert 1 billion strings. This doesn't scale well

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the `appendReplacement` method for this:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
...
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[([a-zA-Z.]+)\\]\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Dear [[user.firstname]] [[user.lastname]]");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String reg1 = m.group(1);
    String value = data.get(reg1);
    m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(value == null ? "" : value));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Comment: You switched the strings. use `Pattern.compile("\\[\\([a-zA-Z.]+)\\]\\]")` and `p.matcher("Dear [[user.firstname]] [[user.lastname]]")`

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd, thanks for the correction, I should have tested the code before posting. Actually I have this snippet bound to a keyboard shortcut in vim so I only had to fill in the pattern, string and replacement.

Answer (score -1):

so, what's the problem?

```
String text = "Dear [[user.firstname]] [[user.lastname]]";
for (String key : data.keySet()) {
    String pattern = key.replace("[", "\\[").replace("]", "\\");
    text = text.replaceAll(pattern, data.get(key));
}
```

Be careful with . Probably you have to duplicate them, i.e. write \\ instead of \. Just debug your code a couple of minutes and the solution is ready.

Comment: Performance is the problem. For example, what if I have megabytes of text and thousands of placeholders in my dictionary?